# IE8 "Save Target as ..." won't display for block elements

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

When you right click an anchor tag in IE you typically get the options

"Open in New Tab"
"Open in New Window"
"Save Target as.."

In IE8 if the content of the anchor tag is either a div or span with "display:block" CSS property then you don't get these options.

I'm trying lots of combinations, but I'm running out of ideas. For example.

```
    a.{
        border: 1px solid red;
        position: absolute;
        display: block;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        text-indent: -9999px;
        z-index: 1000;
    }
```

This would try to cover the entire area with the anchor tag - but I can't see the contents - it's just white!

Here is the issue seen live
http://sci.esa.int/planck/51553-cosmic-microwave-background-seen-by-planck/

It affects the 'Also available as' component on the right - changing the div for a span display:block does not help.

Comment: As an interim solution I am using multiple anchor tags, unfortunately there are 7 in total due to the different combination in which the content can be displayed. To get them highlighting in groups will be another task.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like a slightly quirky end result, but I guess this could possibly be because (under some doctypes at least), a block element is invalid inside an `<a>` element.

(I recall xhtml in strict mode was particularly annoying in this regard, but it's been a while since I worked with it, so my memory may be cloudy)

The reason for this was because `<a>` elements default to being `display:inline`, and it is invalid to have a `block` inside an `inline` element/

The solution to this is to set either the `<a>` element or the block inside it (or both, of course) to be inline-block instead:

```
display:inline-block;
```

Give that a go. Hope it helps.

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<style>
 a { display:inline-block; border: 1px solid red;}
span {display: block}
</style>
 <a href="#">
  test
  <span>test</span>
 </a>
</body>
</html>` I tried this, the first 'test' had the desired menu items - the second did not. It also loses the underline, but remains clickable and the colour is that of a default hyperlink.

Comment: Made the span "inline-block" too - didn't help.

Comment: hmm, interestingly, I pasted your code above into [a jsbin](http://jsbin.com/uqasos/2) and I didn't lose the underline in IE8. Not sure what's different between you and me there. But in any case, I did lose the menu options, which is the main point here, so I guess we can conclude that my suggestion doesn't help. Ultimately, this might be a browser quirk just that can't be resolved. I hope not, but there's a chance it may come to that.

Comment: Apologies, it's the inline-block it lost it's underline. But yes this is besides the point. Thanks for your help

Comment: btw - which IE version do you need to support here? I ask because IE6/7 have bugs with `inline` and `inline-block` that IE8 doesn't have. For IE6/7 you *might* be able to get away with using `inline` for the inner elements, depending on what they're being used for, because bugs in IE6/7 mean they can sometimes treat `inline` as an `inline-block` for layout purposes. You don't have that option for IE8, but if you need to support them all anyway it's worth trying. I'm all out of other suggestions I'm afraid though. Sorry. :-( I'll come back if I think of anything.

Comment: The client has IE8, I don't think we'd like to support anything earlier. Typically to get elements to fall in-line vertically we use display:block, just tried a UL to no avail... really would pain me to have to use a BR

Comment: Same with P tags - I'm considering I might have to put a hyper-link around each element individually...

Comment: meh, heh. yeah, multiple `<a>` tags. That's an option I guess. Pity if it comes to that, but at least it should definitely work. That was the "correct" answer in xhtml strict mode too. It always sucked as a solution.